# Custom time slider

Tags: arcgis-10.0, time

Is there someone who made a custom time slider? Or someone knows where I can find examples or scripts for this subject?
I need a time slider that would work also for years that are B.C. (e.g. 850 BC) and for which I can define an interval like 800 BC - 800 A.D. 
I am archaeologist and it would be great to have such a "tool".
So, basically, I would need a time slider that I can define the years that would be on the slider and when I drag the slider it would make appear on the screen only what is defined to be from that year-decade-century.....
Any clues and ideas working for ArcGIS Desktop 10 are welcomed!

Florela

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for

http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005z0000000z000000.htm

Comment: Or this  http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#//000100000172000000

Comment: It looks like you use a custom date format that includes "gg" for BC or AD (plus a 4 digit year!). See Converting string or numeric time fields into date format: http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//005z00000028000000.htm